# Best way to delete parent/child window hierarchy

Tags: c++, vector, parent, hierarchy

I have a window system in a GUI, and I'm not sure about the destruction sequence. Each Window has a vector holding its children, and each also has a pointer to its parent:

```
auto root = new Window;
root->addChild(new Window);
root->addChild(new Window);
auto child = root->addChild(new Window);  // Return value is the newly created Window
child->addChild(new Window);
child->addChild(new Window);
auto grandchild = child->addChild(new Window);
grandchild->addChild(new Window);
grandchild->addChild(new Window);
grandchild->addChild(new Window);
```

// I want to delete the child pointer, first I need to erase the pointer of it from its parent's children vector.

```
child->parent->children.erase(child->parent->children.begin() + child->positionInParentsVector - 1);

child->destroy();

void Window::destroy()
{
    if (children.size() == 0) delete this;
    else for (auto i : children) i->destroy();
}
```

OR with vectors of smart pointers, would it be sufficient to do:

```
// Remove reference of child from parent's children vector, then

delete child;
```

I have read that it is OK to do delete this. It's hard to get my head around this.

Comment: Smart pointer would probably be best so it is all cleaned up automatically.
However, if your hierarchy is *VERY* deep you might get a stack-overflow in the destructors. In that case you will need to release everything "manually" like you showed.

Comment: Also, because the destroy function is recursive, and I only need to remove the parent's reference once at the very highest level, that means that I need to make one function to remove the reference, and another to do the recursive deletes, right? That would probably be three functions, one removeReferenceAndDestroy, and in that one removeReference, and then do the recursive destroy(). There's no more elegant way?

Comment: If stack overflow *is* a realistic problem (it will also happen for regular hierarchy recursive traversal) then its actually *not* like you showed, you need to do it without recursion but with loops.

Comment: Basically the smart pointer dtor will do what you did automatically.

Comment: If you have an `addChild` shouldn't you have a corresponding `removeChild` to have the parent do the cleanup? And to me `child->destroy()` seems to be what the destructor should do when invoked from `delete child` (but without the `delete this`).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing yourself a bit. The following self contained example has no memory leaks:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using std::vector;
using std::unique_ptr;

struct Window {
    Window() = default;
    vector<unique_ptr<Window>> children;
    Window* parent = nullptr;
    ~Window();

    Window* addChild(std::unique_ptr<Window> c) {
        c->parent = this;
        children.push_back(std::move(c));
        return children.back().get();
    }
};

Window::~Window() = default;

int main() {
    auto root = std::make_unique<Window>();
    root->addChild(std::make_unique<Window>());
    auto child = root->addChild(std::make_unique<Window>());
    child->addChild(std::make_unique<Window>());
};
```

A class cannot contain itself, but it can contain a `unique_ptr` to itself (or containers thereof). In this scheme, all of the recursive destruction happens correctly and automatically. You can dress this up in various ways of course but this is the basic idea.

There are some other questions here of good object and class design and encapsulation, but that's another issue. Note: you should not have a method called `destroy` in the vast majority of cases, but that should instead happen in the destructor.

It should basically never be necessary to write either new or delete in C++11 or greater, unless you are writing relatively low level code (like your own memory allocator).

Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/adef8cc40de4916a

Comment: Thanks. It's interesting how most people tend to stay away from raw pointers, and how the trend of C++ is going. I guess it's a good thing for automatic cleanup, definitely much easier.  A vector of smart pointers is always an extra call, right? Upon destroying the vector each unique_pointer's destructor is called, which then calls delete on the object pointed to.

Comment: @Zebrafish You have to be careful. People stay away from *owning* raw pointers. My code contains both raw pointer member variables (generally a bad thing, but sometimes you need it), and a pointer being returned from a member variable. However, in both cases its a non-owning relationship. Note that in `addChild`, it would be better to check that `c` actually owns a `Window`, and throw if it doesn't. Then you can return a `Window&` which is better as it can't be null (I can change the code if you're curious).

Comment: @Zebrafish An extra call, relative to what? Your description is correct but I don't see how it could be faster if coded with manual rather than automatic cleanup.

Comment: When you std::make_unique<Window> it news a new window, how can it not contain a Window? Do you mean if the allocation failed? Also I'm not understanding why returning a reference to a Window instead of a pointer makes a difference.

Comment: @Zebrafish I'm not sure about your first comment. I said "a class cannot contain itself". A Window does not have a Window member, but it can have a unique_ptr<Window> member. The unique_ptr has an indirection which makes this work. A reference is better because it can't be null, and it doesn't really make any sense to have null windows. Like if someone calls `root->addChild(std::unique_ptr<Window>{});`, you probably want that to throw an exception.